# bootstrap selectpicker not working with angularjs dynamic data load for dropdown

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

It is working for Static dropdown list, but when its applying for dynamic data load with angularjs the selectpicker has been applied, but data's are not loaded.
if I removed this directive from dropdown then datas are loaded perfectly, what is the issue? I have tried more...

Note : the method created using with class so, no issue in that

```
bootselectpicker: function() {
   return {
     restrict: "A",
     require: "ngModel",
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {      
       element.selectpicker();
     }
   }
 }


<select id="special-size" bootselectpicker ng-model="items.selectSize"  ng-options="size.key as size.value for size in products.sizes" ng-change="sizeChange('size',items.selectSize)" class="selectpicker size-droplist">
    <option value="">Select Size</option>                          
</select>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to wait until the DOM is loaded since the SelectPicker is constructed based on the `<option>` -elements inside your `<select>` -element. If the ng-options has not been constructed yet there is no `<option>` -elements and thus the SelectPicker is empty.

You init the SelectPicker after DOM is ready by using Angular's $timeout with no delay. Without delay the $timeout just waits until the DOM is ready and then runs the callback.

Like this:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
   $timeout(function() {      
      element.selectpicker();
   });
}
```

Also, if your `products.sizes` is updated you have to manually run `element.selectpicker('refresh')` since the SelectPicker does not listen for changes in `<option>`s.

Comment: If anyone struck with using selectpicker and angularjs just move to select2 https://select2.org/ as I did and it works flawlessly updates DOM and the select2 is aware of it and updates accordingly no extra code to handle things.

Comment: anyone might wanna check this, works perfect : http://embed.plnkr.co/NV6Vk0AtzJ25tQldgsJx/

Answer (score 7):

a solution to this is the following:

Defining a select like this:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" ng-model="id">
     <option class="small-font" selected value='any'>Anyone</option>
     <option class="small-font" ng-repeat="member in List" data-select-watcher data-last="{{$last}}" value="{{member.id}}">{{member.name}}</option>
</select>
```

and the selectWatcher directive:

```
app.directive('selectWatcher', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var last = attr.last;
            if (last === "true") {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $(element).parent().selectpicker('val', 'any');
                    $(element).parent().selectpicker('refresh');
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

What it does is detect when the last option has been added in the select, and then choose the default option and refresh.

Comment: It create browser hang if we use long dropdown like country

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    },1000)
```

Call this function where you are making your array for ng-repeat or ng-options

Answer (score 0):

try this directive

```js
    .directive('selectPicker', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '?ngModel',
            priority: 10,
            compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                tElement.selectpicker($parse(tAttrs.selectpicker)());
                tElement.selectpicker('refresh');
                return function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                    if (!ngModel) return;

                    scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                        if (!attrs.ngOptions || /track by/.test(attrs.ngOptions)) element.val(newVal);
                        element.selectpicker('refresh');
                    });
                    });

                    ngModel.$render = function () {
                    scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                        element.selectpicker('refresh');
                    });
                    }
                };
            }
            
        };
    }])


this is the html
```

```html
<select class="form-control with-search " select-picker data-live-search="true" title="Select Consumer" ng-model="selectedConsumer"                                          ng-options="c.id as c.firstName + ' ' + c.lastName for c in consumers">
</select>
```